# Help re-caulking the shower with angled gap at the bottom

Tags: bathroom, shower, waterproofing, water-damage, caulk

After seeing some new water damage on the ceiling below my bath, a plumber told me to try regrouting my shower (there were gaps and cracks in the old grout).

How should I approach this area at the bottom?

The tub is at an angle. Before, there was some very, very thick caulk that was peeling away. Should I recaulk?

You can see the edge of where it was before. Do I keep layering caulk until it fills the entire space?

I'm a new DIYer. I can tell whoever did work on my home before did a shoddy job, and I'm trying to do things *correctly* this time. (This sub told me to buy silicone caulk, so I've bought that.)

All suggestions and tips are appreciated. Thanks!!

[image: area of shower with large gap]

[image: The Shower]

[image: Another angle of the area in question]

Comment: Assuming 4"x4" tile, I estimate the gap's widest measurement around 1/2". Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to (re)grout this area.  Nearly all areas where the face of a tile makes a corner should be caulked, because planar joints tend to flex a little bit.  Grout is rigid, and can't handle flexure, whereas caulk is flexible and can.  I would remove the grout and use caulk (you can usually get color-matching caulk).  Use some backer rod if you can fit one in without it protruding too much.

The gaps along the edge a problem only insofar as they allow water to get in and run along the wall to the apron of the tub.  Your tub otherwise has a flange behind the tile that prevents water from leaking behind.  But if the water runs along the edge and down the apron, that's a different story.